# Access Ribbons by id from background thread

Tags: c#, windows, ms-word, ms-office, ribbon

I'm doing a Word 2007 Addin that configure some libraries. So until theses libs are not configured some buttons remains disabled.

How can I access any Ribbon element from the background thread that configure these libraries?

How, using the `Office API`, I can access a element using the element ID as parameter?

Comment: I assume you're getting cross-thread errors when you try it from the same thread (like in WinForms). I'm not an Office developer, but I guess there must be something like `.Invoke` or `.BeginInvoke` to execute code on the GUI thread when called from a secondary thread. Have you tried looking for anything like that?

Comment: @Dai My question is about how access through API the elements. I know that changes in UI elements from cross-thread thow exceptions. But I don't know how access this elements from an ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot access the element directly. All change should be done using callback. The office store in cache the values. If this values are changed by others threads, this thread should invalidate the element cache, using [InvalidateControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa433553%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method.